# what are the methods invoked in the underlying activity when the back button is pressed?

Tags: android, android-activity, adapter

now in my application I invoked another activity on the onItemLongClickListener() of my listView. I edited the data in my next activity , there on save button click I updated the database and finished the activity . **how to get the list to be refreshed automatically? I used notifyDataSetChanged on my adapter in the OnStart and OnResume event . It doesn't seem to work . Can anyone please suggest me what can I do ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override   
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
           //Back button pressed
    }
       return true;
}
```

Comment: the problem is that my list in the previous activity is not being updated . I want it to update it automatically when returning to the activity with the list .

Answer (score 1):

Android 2.0 API introduced the onBackPressed() method, its recommended to override that method instead:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        return;
    }
```

Comment: i used the method as following , but it is still not working. @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 return;
 }

Comment: Sounds like that you are operating on two different instances of your data, are you sure that the data edit view and the adapter are working on the same list/array instance?